# Iphone RSA encryption/Decryption Support

Tags: rsa

i am working on an iphone application which should decrypt a string encrypted by a public key generated by a JAVA program hosted in a remote server.
i was wondering if Iphone SDK Support RSA Encryption. If So how should i proceed to accomplish this task

Answer (score 0):

Look in Docs. You can also try to use openssl for decrypting stuff: http://www.x2on.de/2010/07/13/tutorial-iphone-app-with-compiled-openssl-1-0-0a-library/